# How to get id from include? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I having problem for getting element id from include? function in controller level.

```
def payslip_report
if params[:teacher_id] and params[:month_year].present?
   @month_and_year =   params[:month_year].gsub(' ','')
   @teacher_data   =   TeacherPayslip.where(:teacher_id => params[:teacher_id])
   @salary = Array.new
   @teacher_data.each do |i|
   a = i.salary_date.strftime("%B%Y")
   @salary << a 
end
   #raise @salary.inspect
   if @salary.include?(@month_and_year)
    raise "1"
  else
    raise "2"
  end
```

end

end

In if @salary.include?(@month_and_year) means, if it's true means, how to get id for included element.Using that id I can get all attribute for that id. Please guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` to filter out matching records:

```
@matched_records = @teacher_data.
                   select{|t| t.salary_date.strftime("%B%Y") == @month_and_year}
# => returns an array of TeacherPayslip records with matching month and year

if @matched_records.blank?
   //no match found
else
   first_match = @matched_records.first
end
```

Other, possibly better, solution is to do it all in db query by using month and year functions on the `salary_date`.